# cannot change sql server 2008 express installation folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQl Server 2008 Express (not R2, and I can't move to that) on windows 2003.

I downloaded SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe from the Microsoft site and am going thru the installer.

I want to install it on a different drive, however I can't see any options to change this, they are all greyed out/disabled.

[image]

How can I install this to the drive I want?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the shared path is to remove all SQL products using add/remove programs, probably reboot, then change it on the first SQL product install.  If there is no SQL on the server then the shared feature can be changed but once it is set you are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The "Shared Feature directory" has the default of C drive. It cannot be changed.

Comment: Is that even the installation directory?

Comment: -1, I dont think your response adds anything you couldnt deduce from looking at the image. What are your sources?